# How to get values based on each last valid occurrence in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

| Status | Energy |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 12 |
| 0 | 13 |
| 0 | 11 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 15 |
| 0 | 14 |

I have Dataframe with two columns: status and energy. I am trying to create a new column for energy loss based on the last occurrence of each status. I have already tried cumsum with resetting, but it's not working. Looking for results like the below table. Just copying the Energy column value to result in column based on the last of each status occurrence.

```
|Status |Energy |Result_outcome|
|:----  |:----  |:----        |
|1      |2      |NaN          |
|1      |3      |NaN          |
|1      |2      |NaN          |
|1      |4      |4            |
|0      |12     |NaN          |
|0      |13     |NaN          |
|0      |11     |11           |
|1      |3      |3            |
|0      |15     |NaN          |
|0      |14     |14           |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us use `shift` to compare the current row and next row then update the values in result column based on the outcome of comparison

```
df.loc[df['Status'] != df['Status'].shift(-1), 'result'] = df['Energy']
```

---

```
   Status  Energy  result
0       1       2     NaN
1       1       3     NaN
2       1       2     NaN
3       1       4     4.0
4       0      12     NaN
5       0      13     NaN
6       0      11    11.0
7       1       3     3.0
8       0      15     NaN
9       0      14    14.0
```

Comment: Thanks @subham Its working fine. However it will be great if you can explain bit more about logic behind shift(-1)

Comment: @prashantthakre The logic is easy: We would like to create a boolean mask to identify the rows where the value in current row of Status columns is not equal to the value in the next row essentially this would help us identify the boundaries. then with `loc` we can fill the values in result column at boundary positions.